# How to implement cumulative distribution function using interval alpha, beta and X in Python?

Tags: python, math, distribution, cdf

How do I plot/code the cumulative distribution function using parameters alpha, beta and X as intervals, rather than real values. i.e.: alpha would be = [0.5;1.2] instead of just a "normal" value like 0.5?

Code above:

```
alpha = self.alpha
beta = self.beta
cdf = btdtr(alpha, beta, x)

return cdf
```

My problem is that btdtr doesn't accept intervals as values/parameters of alpha, beta and X, only real numbers.

Is there a way that I could use intervals as parameters or another function that does the same thing to obtain the CDF??

Comment: Some more context would be helpful.  You use `btdtr`; is that from `scipy.special`?   That implies that you are talking about the beta distribution.  Is that correct?  Could you give a concrete example of what you mean by "using intervals"?

Comment: I use spicy.stats; Yes, it's beta distribution;

Comment: For example, in Excel/LibreOffice Calc, if you use "Beta.Dist" with x = .2222, alpha = 1.7778, beta = 2.2222, the result would be 0,187006122799940. What I'm trying to do is make alpha and beta an interval, like [1.7 to 1.8], for example, instead of just one number.

Comment: But btdtr doesn't let me do that - use intervals as  alpha and beta entries.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being dense, but I don't understand what result you expect when `alpha` is an interval.  You *can* pass multiple values in each argument of `scipy.special.btdtr`; in that case, the arguments are broadcast according to numpy's broadcasting rules.  But I don't think that is what you mean.  Could you give at least one explicit example of the inputs *and the expected output* that demonstrates what you mean by "using intervals"?

Comment: Like @WarrenWeckesser, I have no idea what you're asking.  Please edit your question to explain what you mean, preferably with a use-case.

Comment: @LucasLisboa Do you want matrix as output? Because if you use some `alpha` interval for, say, rows and `beta` interval for columns this is what you'll get back - matrix of values for Beta CDF